# Postgres Average Filter based on date

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am having a postgres table which is updated by a cron for every hour. I need average of that volume based on 1 day, 5 day, 10 day. when i average it like this

```
select avg(volume), id from price_table where NOW() > updated_at::timestamptz
    AND NOW() - updated_at::timestamptz <= interval '5 day' group by id and order by avg(price).
```

This is taking only the average of all the entries but i want an average where it will take an average of each day and then add the average of all days based on the number of days we provide.

My table example

```
id | volume| name | updated_at
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-12 03:06:53.981
1  | 75   | apple| 2022-05-12 03:06:53.981
2  | 57   | orang| 2022-05-12 03:06:53.981
2  | 56   | orang| 2022-05-12 03:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-13 01:00:02.793
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-13 01:00:02.793
2  | 76   | orang| 2022-05-13 01:00:02.793
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-13 04:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-14 01:00:02.530
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-14 01:00:02.530
2  | 16   | orang| 2022-05-14 01:00:02.530
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-14 03:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-15 03:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-15 03:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-15 03:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-15 03:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-16 03:06:53.981
2  | 16   | apple| 2022-05-16 03:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-16 03:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-16 03:06:53.981
1  | 56   | apple| 2022-05-16 03:06:53.981
```

so when i search for the volume of 7 days, it needs to take the average of each day and sum it up for just the 7 days grouped by the id

Could anyone help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are summing the averages.

That said, break it into two parts.  First find the daily average.  Then sum the last seven days' daily averages:

```
with daily_avgs as (
  select id, updated_at::date as ddate, avg(volume) as day_avg
    from price_table
   group by id, ddate
)
select id, ddate, 
       sum(day_avg) over (partition by id
                              order by ddate
                      range between '7 days' preceding
                                and current row) as sum_day_avg
  from daily_avgs;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8b3148e8070b49871793686fb3fd2b76)*

Comment: the second sum part for the last seven days did not work

Comment: @AjayAntonyraj What failed?  What version of Postgres are you running?

Comment: The statement "did not work" by itself is **totally useless**.  How did it not work: it give incorrect result, they what were you expecting and explain why that expectation. Did the statement generate an error? If so what is the exact complete error? Something else then what exactly?